# Linq and XML : Only second part of Attribute Name displayed

Tags: c#, linq, xsd

I am in the process to familiarise myself with Linq and XML. 
As part of this I am not just using an XML I am also using an XML Schema. (xsd).

My xsd starts with: `<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="report">`

Stepping through my xsd goes well. I am able to get the various elements and attributes. So, I am able to identify `schema` as an `XElement` and whatever follows after `scheme` (`xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="report"`) as an `XAttribute`.(actually a collection of 2 attributes).

My question is: Why is the Attribute Name of the first `XAttribute` identified as `xs` rather than `xmlns:xs`?

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the LINQ to XML programming interface, namespaces are represented in the XML tree as attributes. You can use the [IsNamespaceDeclaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xattribute.isnamespacedeclaration?view=netframework-4.7.2) property to determine if a particular LINQ to XML attribute (XAttribute) is really a namespace declaration.